How to fix The selector "app-gif" did not match any elements
I get the error in console "The selector "app-gif" did not match any elements"
Any ideas what should i change or do?
This is gif.component.ts
// gif.component.ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-gif',
  template: `
    <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
    <img [src]="src" alt="Gif">
  `,
})
export class GifComponent implements OnInit {
  title: string = '';
  src: string = '';

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.title = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('title') || '';
    this.src = `assets/${this.title}.gif`;
  }
}

app.module.ts looks like this :
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router'; // Import RouterModule
import { GifComponent } from '../gif/gif.component';
import { GifDetailComponent } from '../gif/gif-detail.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    GifComponent,
    GifDetailComponent,
    
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CommonModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    RouterModule, // Add RouterModule to imports array
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [GifComponent, GifDetailComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }

App.component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, RouterLink, RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';
import { NgFor } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  standalone: true,
  imports: [RouterLink, RouterOutlet, NgFor]
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'compiled';
  gifs = [
    { title: 'gif1', src: 'assets/gif1.gif' },
    { title: 'GIF2', src: 'assets/gif2.gif' },
    // Gifs
  ];

  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  redirectToGif(gif: { title: string, src: string }) {
    this.router.navigate(['/gif', gif.title]);
  }
}

Any idea what can be a problem here?
there is a github version also : https://github.com/BekaEn/GifApp

What's the actual error? The error in the title is different from the error in the question.

Probably a typo

So which is correct, title or question? Anc could you show your main.ts? Because on github you dont use standalone components, so its probably different with standalone app component you posted here

First thing I noticed is that you have some logic in 'then', after bootstrapModule(). I don't think it's needed, it's enough to just biotstrap a module. Inside module you define which conponent you use

When i click on the gif it should redirect me to the page but i get this error "I get the error in console "The selector "app-gif" did not match any elements"
